Chrome won't start before Ubuntu 22.04 is suspended at least once after booting
For a couple of weeks now, I can't open Google Chrome on my Ubuntu system normally.
While experimenting to come up with a solution, I discovered, that everything works fine if I come back from my regular pause, for which I usually close down my laptop, which makes the system hibernate/suspend.
I reinstalled google-chrome-stable, but this behavior did not change.
Even running from terminal does not help, if I type $ google-chrome-stable, the process is stuck, there is no error message (or any feedback), it does not terminate but nothing opens.
I would really appreciate some help as this really affects my workflow negatively.
Thank You so much in advance!
Peter
